# UI Alternative to showing search controller at top of page?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to add a search display controller but would like to avoid permanently consuming valuable real estate at top of table view controller.  Can anyone suggest a tutorial or approach to display search box dynamically when user touches a small icon, swipes or otherwise takes an action to trigger the search capability?

Realize this is not a code question.  It is UI question.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: This probably belongs better at http://ux.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

You could add a right bar button with a search icon to your navigation controller and have it do a push segue to a new table View controller with a search bar imbedded in the navigation titleView